# Artifactory gradle and properties mutation by artifactoryPublish task DSL

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

My problem with build-info-extractor gralde plugin for artifactory

Source code with example for reproduce problem: [https://github.com/lavcraft/gradle-artifactory-build-info-extractor-problems](http://github.com/lavcraft/gradle-artifactory-build-info-extractor-problems)

1. Configure environment – `artifactory_user` `artifactory_password` `artifactory_contextUrl`
2. Run `./gradlew build aP`
3. See jar artifacts properties in you artifactory instance

I expect, that this example (see below) works perfectly

```
artifactoryPublish {
  properties = ['aa':'aaa']
  properties {
    nebula '**:**:**:*@*', 'not_added_prop':'sub0'
  }
}
```

*see sub0/build.gradle* in github project

But it does not work. What is wrong with my example?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the cause of this issue.
Here's the artifactory closure configured in the build.gradle file, in the project you shared:

```
artifactory {
  contextUrl = project.findProperty('artifactory_contextUrl')
  publish {
      repository {
        repoKey = 'libs-snapshot-local'
        username = project.findProperty('artifactory_user')
        password = project.findProperty('artifactory_password')
      }

      defaults {
        publications('nebula')
        publishConfigs('archives')
        publishIvy = false
        properties {
          nebula '*:*:*:*@*', 'want_to_add':'but not' // add only to *.pom artifacts. Why?
          mavenJava commonProperties, '*:*:*:*@*'
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

As you can see above, the closure includes one publication (nebula) and one configuration (archives).
Running the build script as is prompts the following deployed artifacts:

$ gradle clean artifactoryPublish

```
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub0/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub0-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub0/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub0-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub1/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub1-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub1/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub1-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Now, if you comment out the publication as follows:

```
//publications('nebula')
publishConfigs('archives')
```

You can the following:

```
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub0/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub0-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ru/alfalab/platform/tests/sub1/0.1.1-SNAPSHOT/sub1-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So it looks like both the archives configuration and the nebula publication contribute the same two artifacts above. 
Since "want_to_add" property is configured on the nebula publication (and not on the archives publication), the 2 jars contributed by the configuration don't get the property.

A simple fix for this is issue is to remove the archives configuration:

```
publications('nebula')
//publishConfigs('archives')
```

Alternatively, if for some reason you do want to have both the configuration and publication, you can add the property to your configuration as well. Here's how you do this:

```
properties = ['want_to_add': 'but not']
```

So the full closure, with both the publication, configuration and properties for both is this:

```
defaults {
        publications('nebula')
        publishConfigs('archives')
        publishIvy = false
        properties = ['want_to_add': 'but not']              
        properties {
          nebula '*:*:*:*@*', 'want_to_add':'but not' // add only to *.pom artifacts. Why?
          mavenJava commonProperties, '*:*:*:*@*'
        }
      }
```

You can read more about this here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

Comment: Gradle publications automatically configure pom.xml generation (nebula imrove info and dependencies in pom.xml). I want to use publications plugin for java components and archives to reports and documentation.

I can`t use properties = [], because it spread to all artifacts

Two cases:

* nice plugin for configure artifactory closure
* user, who uses this plugin must have abilty to reconfigure default behaviour (from plugin)
But in this case, properties closure does not work in subproject. If you want i can create project with plugin and my projects structure for demonstrate full case